# is there any possible way to run a python script on boot in windows operating system?

Tags: python, windows

I want to run a python script which should always start when windows boot.
i believe i can create an executable windows executable file from python by using py2exe... But how to make as a start up service which will be triggered while boot

Is there any way ?

Comment: There's nothing special about Python in this question. You'd run a Python program the same way you'd run any other program at boot. What's giving you trouble with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a `py2exe` executable for this, you can simply run the Python executable itself (assuming it's installed of course), passing the name of your script as an argument.

And one way to do that is to use the task scheduler, which can create tasks to be run at boot time, under any user account you have access to.